# Are USB flash drives better than SSD, To archive data for long periods of time?

Tags: ssd

I need to archive some family photos ,videos,and some music... so i will write the data only once...and then keep it stored. I don't want to use a HDD

I read some sites , claim that:

Compared to SSDs, USB flash drives and memory cards can permanently store information even if there is no power applied for long periods. Data written on non-volatile flash memory can last for 10 years at a minimum and possibly longer...

on the other hard

I read that ,SSDs,if no power applied for long periods,Data can be lost.

which one to choose

SSDs vs USB flash drives,with no power applied for long periods ?